# Is there an API for Aardvark?

Tags: java, php, python

Is there an API for Aardvark (http://vark.com)? How can I programmatically ask questions and get answers?

Comment: Have you tried asking Aardvark itself?

Answer (score 1):

Since their website do not seems to provide an API, you'll have to rely upon the old, brutal and nevertheless efficient (as long as the site do not change) html scanning of pages.

Using java platform, i would suggest you to use Groovy goodness, like [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper), which allow one to parse an XML document with ease.

Besides, a fast googling told me that [they're thinking about it](http://community.vark.com/pages/18354-general/suggestions/258180-cater-to-programmers-and-web-developers?ref=title).

Comment: Has anyone come up with a Perl script or anything that lets you download your own questions and answers? I've started on one, but if there's an existing solution, I'd prefer it.